# ¿Cómo pongo en mayusculas este array?

Tags: php, sql, laravel

Buenas tengo este metodo en donde realizo una consulta, pero quiero traer todo en mayusculas o tansiquiera la columna "unidad_descripcion" de la tabla ""

```
    public static function consultar_nuevosProductos(){

    $consulta = DB::select("SELECT vcomp_productos_web1.*, ped_unidades_medida.unidad_descripcion FROM vcomp_productos_web1 INNER JOIN ped_unidades_medida ON vcomp_productos_web1.unidad = ped_unidades_medida.unidad_uid
        WHERE vcomp_productos_web1.id IN 
    (
        SELECT MAX(vcomp_productos_web1.id) FROM vcomp_productos_web1 INNER JOIN ped_unidades_medida ON ped_unidades_medida.unidad_uid = vcomp_productos_web1.unidad
        WHERE vcomp_productos_web1.marca = 'forte' and vcomp_productos_web1.venta_web = 'SI' 
        GROUP BY vcomp_productos_web1.categoria
    ) 
    ORDER BY vcomp_productos_web1.id DESC");

        $consultas = array_map('strtoupper', $consulta);

        return $consultas;
}
```

El error es el siguiente:

> ```
> strtoupper() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given
> in vcomp_productos_web1.php line 92
> ```

En mi lina #92 tengo lo siguiente.

```
        $consultas = array_map('strtoupper', $consulta);
```

Answer (score 1):

Al parecer el objeto `$consulta` no es un array de string para que pueda ser mapeado y convertido a mayuscula.

No se el formato en como returna la funcion `Db::select` el query pero supongamos que sea por indice, entonces tienes que utilizar la propiedad del resultado, no el objeto, cuando vas a mostrar los datos uno por uno.

Por ejemplo si es por indice que lo retorna entonces seria asi:

```
foreach($value as $consulta){
 echo strtoupper($resultadot[0]["unidad_descripcion"]);
}
```

Fijate como se aplico el `strtoupper` a al indice no al objeto en si.

Answer (score 0):

El error sucede porque la variable `$consulta` es una colección/array de 2 niveles:

```
[
    0 => [],
    1 => [],
    2 => []
]
```

Por lo tanto necesitas iterar 2 veces, lo puedes lograr de manera sencilla con los métodos para las colecciones de laravel:

```php
$consultaMinuscula = $consulta->map(function ($item, $key) {
    return array_map('strtoupper', $item->all());
})->all();
```

Estoy asumiendo que son colleciones por lo que en caso no lo sean, deberás quitar `->all()` donde lo requiera.